# Possible to call a parent javascript function from an ajax child?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using ajax to refresh the contents of a div.  Inside that ajax script, a new count, called myTasks, is created in a session variable (`$_SESSION['myTasks']`).

Also within that ajax script, I'm checking the new value against the session value before reassigning the session value to the new value.  If the new value is greater than the one in the session variable, I would like to play a chime sound - which is about 2 seconds in length.  I have the following code to make the chime sound play:

```
<audio src="./sounds/newTask.wav" id="newTaskSound" preload="auto"></audio>
```

This worked just fine in the sense that it started to play the sound.  However, my ajax timer is set to go off every second, thus the sound was being cut off (at best) half way through playing... more often then not, only a quarter of the chime was being played.

What I would like to do is this: If the new myTasks count is greater than the session variable, call a javascript function in the main page (same one that contains the ajax call functions).

My question is this:  How can I get the ajax "child" to call the html "parent" functions?  I've tried several things, such as:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.playNewTask.call();</script>
```

but I can't get anything to work.

Is there a way to call a javascript function from the ajax child?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by parent/child? A recursive call? That could get really expensive on your server resources. The way I am reading your question it looks like you want to do this: `function parent(){ $.ajax({.... parent() .... }); }`

Comment: by parent, I mean the file loaded in the browser url (i.e. index.php)  by child, i mean the ajax page that index.php calls

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see more of your code to get a better idea of how you're doing this.

If you're using an iframe, you can only call functions in the parent (top) window if the url's of the page and iframe match.

Otherwise, there's no reason to use window.top, since both functions would be in the same document scope.

You may also consider setting a delete timer for the `<audio>` tag - use `setTimeout` and delete this audio tag after 2 (or 2.5, to be safe) seconds. Then append new audio tags. That should keep the chime from cutting off, and give you overlapping chime sounds if the integer is increased every time you check.

You could also use a `setTimeout` to change a variable, and prevent the audio tag from being replaced until it is done playing.